# set cookie session deadbolt 2 in controller

Tags: deadbolt-2

I'm new deadbolt 2, code sample have hardcode check in MyDeadboltHandler
    AuthorisedUser.findByUserName("steve")
and I see an other example
'final Http.Cookie userCookie = context.request().cookie("user");'
in MyDeadboltHandler

but I don't know set cookie in controller
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your user logs in, you can just write the cookie directly into the session, and it will be passed to the client in the response.

From the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaSessionFlash#Storing-data-into-the-Session)

```
public Result login() {
    session("connected", "user@gmail.com");
    return ok("Welcome!");
}
```

In your case, the cookie key is up to you to define, and the email address or username may come from a form submitted with the credentials.

Comment: Thank for reply, another problem occur with me, I have 4 group: admin, service, user, guest, admin is created in database, the first time admin login required change password, I want to redirect to form change password and only admin need that, I set redirect in onAuthFailure, but service, user, guest that not authentication in some action and redirect change password form, have a good idea, please tell me, how every role redirect an other link? , I just read document about deadbolt in 2 day, can I don't understand more, sorry for my English.

Comment: There's an easy answer, but it's best if you create a new question - this makes it easier for people to find answers to specific questions.  Link to the question here and I'll answer it immediately.

Comment: I just ask question in stackoverflow, thank for advice : )
Link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848416/deadbolt-play-java-change-password-the-first-time-login