# Deadbolt play java Change password the first time login

Tags: java, playframework, deadbolt

I have 4 group: admin, service, user, guest, admin is created in database, the first time admin login required change password, I want to redirect to form change password and only admin need that, I set redirect in onAuthFailure, but service, user, guest that not authentication in some action and redirect change password form, have a good idea, please tell me, what should I do for every role redirect an other link? , I just read document about deadbolt in 2 day, can I don't understand more, sorry for my English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `DeadboltHandler` implementation, the `onAuthFailure` method can use the `getSubject` to get the current user, and through that, the roles held by the user.

```
public class MyDeadboltHandler implements DeadboltHandler {
    private final DeadboltExecutionContextProvider executionContextProvider;
    private final DeadboltAnalyzer analyzer;

    @Inject
    public MyDeadboltHandler(final ExecutionContextProvider ecProvider,
                             final DeadboltAnalyzer analyzer) {
        this.executionContextProvider = ecProvider.get();
        this.analyzer =analyzer;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> onAuthFailure(Http.Context context,
                                                 Optional<String> content) {
        final ExecutionContext executionContext = executionContextProvider.get();
        final ExecutionContextExecutor executor = HttpExecution.fromThread(executionContext);
        return getSubject(context).thenApplyAsync(maybeSubject ->
            maybeSubject.map(subject -> analyzer.hasRole(maybeSubject, "admin") ? /*go to admin section*/
                                                                                : /*go to non-admin section*/)
                        .orElseGet(() -> /*no user present*/),
                                   executor);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Anywhere there's a comment in that example, e.g. `/*go to admin section*/` you need to replace it with a `Result`.

There are other methods available in `DeadboltAnalyzer`, so you can have more complex checks than just `analyzer.hasRole(maybeSubject, "admin")` if necessary.

Comment: Thank for code of you, but I don't familiar with lambda expression and concurrent, when I replace `/*go to admin section*/` with Result, they ok, but `/*no user present*/` replace with Result, error. Sorry for my stupid.